# Two Turtlebot3 using slam toolbox to create their own map in a Gazebo World

Tags: gazebo, slam, turtlebot3, multi-robot, tf-tree

This is my first post in this forum. I am new in the field and currently working on a project. My goal is to have  two turtlebot3 in a gazebo world and allow them to create their own map using slam toolbox, separately.

After an attempt of writing a single launch file to spawn two tb3, I ran into a problem where my tf tree did not appear properly. Therefore, I decided to go step by step.

As the first step, I tried to spawn only single tb3 in an empty world to see if I can set its namespace and tf tree properly. Here is the tf tree: [image]

Here is the nodes list:

[image]

Here is the topics list:

[image]

I modified the existing launch files of "turtlebot3_gazebo" packages as the following:

```
def generate_launch_description():

use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='false')
urdf_file_name = 'turtlebot3_waffle.urdf'

urdf_path = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_gazebo'),
    'urdf',
    urdf_file_name)

with open(urdf_path, 'r') as infp:
    robot_desc = infp.read()

return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_sim_time',
        default_value='false',
        description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

    Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        namespace='/tb3_1',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{
            'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
            'robot_description': robot_desc,
            'frame_prefix': 'tb3_1/',
        }],
    ),
```

launch file 2

```
def generate_launch_description():

model_folder = 'turtlebot3_waffle'
sdf_path = os.path.join(
    get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_gazebo'),
    'models',
    model_folder,
    'model.sdf'
)

# Launch configuration variables specific to simulation
x_pose = LaunchConfiguration('x_pose', default='0.0')
y_pose = LaunchConfiguration('y_pose', default='0.0')

# Declare the launch arguments
declare_x_position_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'x_pose', default_value='0.0',
    description='Specify namespace of the robot')

declare_y_position_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'y_pose', default_value='0.0',
    description='Specify namespace of the robot')

start_gazebo_ros_spawner_cmd = Node(
    package='gazebo_ros',
    executable='spawn_entity.py',
    namespace='/tb3_1',
    arguments=[
        '-entity', 'waffle',
        '-robot_namespace', '/tb3_1',
        '-file', sdf_path,
        '-x', x_pose,
        '-y', y_pose,
        '-z', '0.01'
    ],
    output='screen',
)
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can point out the problem here. I did not understand why odom -> base_footprint transform stays alone apart from the rest of the tree. I was expecting to see /tb3_1/odom -> /tb3_1/base_footprint as the parent node of this tree.

In addition, any comment or other sources to this problem are welcomed. I've investigated a lot of discussions and other projects about multiple robots doing their own slam(to create separate maps) in the same world. However, I do not have enough knowledge about the terminology to point out them here.

My system is Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS Humble. Its been only a month since I started studying mobile robotics, and I am not a computer scientist so I am learning both robotics and programming.

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Best,

noob_robot_31

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)....